# Disable row hide/show when click on the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

Combine with datatables, I'm using the following code to hide/show more details and it applies at the row level instead of the first column (and I want it this way). At the same time I also have the checkbox in one of the column.

The problem is when I click on the checkbox, it will show/hide the entire row.

**How to allow me to click on the checkbox without trigger the hide/show?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 'tr'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      targets: 0,
      orderable: false
    }],
    searching: false
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title>My Company</title>
  
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <style>
    .big-checkbox {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Invoice No.</th>
          <th>Due Date</th>
          <th>Invoice Amount</th>
          <th>Outstanding Amount</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC Company</td>
          <td>C1010</td>
          <td>2017-09-27 00:00:00</td>
          <td>111</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>PENDING</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Zoozle Inc</td>
          <td>C0432</td>
          <td>2017-09-27 00:00:00</td>
          <td>111</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please share code snippet

Comment: hi, added. You need to resize to a certain degree until u saw the `plus` icon. It is responsive :)

Comment: sorry but it is not showing any plus icon

Comment: sorry forgot to include the responsive js. There it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try now

you need bind click event for checkbox and need to use stopPropagation(); to prevent click event that is passing to its parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e){
      debugger;
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 'tr'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      targets: 0,
      orderable: false
    }],
    searching: false
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title>My Company</title>
  
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <style>
    .big-checkbox {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Invoice No.</th>
          <th>Due Date</th>
          <th>Invoice Amount</th>
          <th>Outstanding Amount</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC Company</td>
          <td>C1010</td>
          <td>2017-09-27 00:00:00</td>
          <td>111</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>PENDING</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox"></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Zoozle Inc</td>
          <td>C0432</td>
          <td>2017-09-27 00:00:00</td>
          <td>111</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the responsive extension attachs four event handlers to `<tbody>` each time the table is drawn.

Thus a handler to override responsive must be regenerated after each draw as well :

```
drawCallback: function() {
  $('#example tbody td').on('keyup mouseup mousedown click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.type == 'checkbox') {
      e.stopPropagation()
    }  
  })
},
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/eyLne5e7/**